# How is the WeatherForecastController in template Blazor application configured to return JSON?

Tags: json, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I created a standard Blazor Client application, but found when adding any new API controllers they simply do not work.

Even just copying the `WeatherForecastController` to a `WeatherForecast2Controller` returns the same error (as an HTML error page is returned instead of any JSON data):

`'<' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.`

I assume there must be some configuration somewhere to tell it what return type to expect, but no idea where to look. The only controller that returns valid JSON data is the `WeatherForecastController` you get out of the box.

Works:
`group = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<GenericGroup[]>($"WeatherForecast");`

Fails:
`group = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<GenericGroup[]>($"WeatherForecast2");`

Controllers are identical aside from name (literally copied the existing controller). I have been through every single file in the solution and don't see anything that would cause `WeatherForecast` to be a special routing.

### Clue 1:

It does not hit a breakpoint in any controller aside from the `WeatherForecastController`

### Clue 2:

The HTML returned (which causes the Json deserialise to fail) is actually the initial `Loading...` from the Blazor client load, so it looks like the requests are going to the standard routing and not treated as API calls.

### Clue 3:

This does not happen unless authentication has been added to the application. I tried it on a vanilla Blazor app (no auth) and it works just fine. The failing app is using Azure B2C for auth.

Comment: Are you sure that the return value is not some kind of html error text triggered by some internal operation? Do you have a proper try/catch around the controller actions?

Comment: @Steve See above. If I simply copy the existing controller to a different name, it fails. If I put new code into the existing controller, it works. Driving me slightly insane. See clue added. Breakpoints in new controllers are never hit.

Comment: check F12 developer tools and network tab. It will at least give you an error. It seems to me like the address you trying to hit with your api does not exists, thus it retrieves index.html (which starts with `<` - invalid json)...
Check the address and check swagger.

Comment: @Alamakanambra It is basically trying to reload the app, instead of accessing the API endpoint. We are talking the different between `group = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<GenericGroup[]>($"WeatherForecast");` and `group = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<GenericGroup[]>($"WeatherForecast2");`. First works, Second fails. Controllers are identical aside from name

Comment: I will close this question. It turns out I had the wrong logger generic parameter specified which messed it all up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can cause things to blow up if you inject the wrong logger parameter in the generic `ILogger<>`. It was the one thing I missed changing. Good to know.